# Add - between 3 characters

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string which contain characters, spaces & -, and I want to remove the white spaces & - .. then add a - for each 3 characters, I tried this:

```
string  cleanedstring = S.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-","");
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, cleanedstring.Length / 3).Select(i => cleanedstring.Substring(i * 3, 3));
var res = string.Join("-", list);
return res;
```

but in case I have `888372789` the function will correctly return `888-372-789`.. but if the string = `11-43  48 5555 8351` then I will get `114-348-555-583` instead of `114-348-555-583-51`.. any advice ?

Comment: `cleanedstring.Length / 3` will truncate the number, so if it's not evenly divisible by 3 then you'll be missing content.  Instead use `(int) Math.Ceil(cleanedstring.Length / 3.0)`

Answer (score 1):

`cleanedstring.Length / 3` will truncate the number, so if it's not evenly divisible by `3` then you'll be missing content.

For example, `14 / 3 = 4`, instead of `4.666...`, due to the truncation.

Instead, for `14 / 3 = 4`, we want it to be `5`, so instead we can do:

```
(int) Math.Ceil(cleanedstring.Length / 3.0)
```

For the changes, converting `/ 3` to `/ 3.0` will ensure we're doing floating point division, preserving the decimal places (ensuring the result is `4.666...` instead of `4`).

Then we use `Math.Ceil(4.666...)` to convert it to `5.0`, and then we cast the result to `(int)` since `Enumerable.Range` only deals with integers.

EDIT:

To solve the problem with `Substring` going past the end of the string, you can use `Math.Min`.

```
var subject = "11-43  48 5555 8351".Replace(" ", "").Replace("-","");
        
var list = Enumerable
    .Range(0, (int) Math.Ceiling(subject.Length / 3.0))
    .Select(i => subject.Substring(i * 3, Math.Min(3, subject.Length - i * 3)));
        
var res = string.Join("-", list);
        
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Doing `Math.Min(3, subject.Length - i * 3)` will ensure that the value we're passing to `Substring` will not exceed the length of the string, so when `i=4` in our example, the result will be `2` instead of the value `3` which would exceed the end of the string by `1` character.

To get the expected result of `114-348-555-583-51`

Comment: ,, i will get this error `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex + length cannot exceed length of string.` on some text

Comment: i tried this `var list = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling(cleanedstring.Length / 3.0)).Select(i => cleanedstring.Substring(i * 3, 3));`

Comment: Lemme update the answer, yes the `Substring` part will complain without changing it.

Comment: maybe i should be clearer now if for example i got this number `0 - 11 1975--314` the final result should be `022-198-53-24` so i final 2 parts should be 2 nd not 3 & 2

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, do you want to evaluate part of the mathematical equation and NOT just add dashes every 3 characters?

Comment: for example i got this number `0 - 11 1975--314` the final result should be `011-197-53-14` so i final 2 parts should be of length 2 and not of length 3 & 2

Comment: Can you update your question with all the possible outcomes?  Your title is stated as `Add - between 3 characters`, but you're saying that sometimes it's between `2` characters instead.  It's very hard to give a correct answer without all the information.

Comment: ok will do.. but mainly if the final part is less than 3 then i need the final 2 blocks to be of length 2

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use a method, i would provide one that is optimized instead of one that just works but is very inefficient. Here you should use a `StringBuilder` and a `for-loop`. For example:

```
public static string CleanString(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    sb.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");
    if(sb.Length <= 3) return sb.ToString();
    int offset = sb.Length % 3;
    if(offset == 0) offset = 3;
    for(int i = sb.Length - offset; i > 0; i-=3)
    {
        sb.Insert(i, "-");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

[Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DcTpK0)

Your new special rules:

> With 3 digits at the end its fine, with 1 at end split the last 4 into
> 2 groups, with 2 at end it's fine too. Correct?

You:

> Yes exactly, `0 - 11 1975--314` should become `011-197-53-14`

Try this:

```
public static string CleanString(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    sb.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");
    if(sb.Length <= 3) return sb.ToString();
    int offset = sb.Length % 3;
    if(offset == 0) 
        offset = 3;
    else if(offset == 1)
    {
        // your special rule, split last 4 into groups of 2
        offset = 9;
        sb.Insert(sb.Length - 2, "-");
        if(sb.Length > 5)
        {
            sb.Insert(sb.Length - 5, "-");
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = sb.Length - offset; i > 0; i -= 3)
    {
        sb.Insert(i, "-");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

[Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ar4Nlu)

Comment: maybe i should be clearer now if for example i got this number `0 - 11 1975--314` the final result should be `011-197-53-14` so i final 2 parts should be of length 2 and not of length 3 & 2

Comment: @JohnJohn: Yes, you should be clearer before people trying to help. Can you explain the rules and provide all edge cases and the desired results?

Comment: @Time Schmelter i realized this after i run my test cases

Comment: @JohnJohn: So with 3 digits at the end its fine, with 1 at end split the last 4 into 2 groups, with 2 at end it's fine too. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach

```
string s = "11-43  48 5555 8351";
string cleanedstring = s.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");
double partSize = 3;
int k = 0;
var output = cleanedstring
            .ToLookup(c => Math.Floor(k++ / partSize))
            .Select(e => new String(e.ToArray()));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", output));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are times I really like LINQ and there are times I believe it just complicates things. This is (IMO) one of those times.

Once you strip the `string` of all the noise. I would just do this:

```
    private static string InsertSeperatorAtInterval(string source, string sep, int block)
    {
        if(source.Length <= block) return source;

        string result = source;
        int step = block + 1;
        
        for(int i = block; i < result.Length; i+=step)
        {
            result = result.Insert(i, sep);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This works because the `Length` of the resulting string changes each time the "separator" is inserted and at intervals (block + 1)...the 1 is to accommodate the newly add separator.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
        string inputText = "11-43  48 5555 8351";
        string inputTextWithoutWhiteSpaces = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"\s+", "");              // removes whitespaces
        inputTextWithoutWhiteSpaces = Regex.Replace(inputTextWithoutWhiteSpaces, @"[-]", "");   // removes -

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var subStringMax3 in Regex.Matches(inputTextWithoutWhiteSpaces, ".{1,3}"))  // populates substring
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)  // contains some text
            {
                sb.Append($"-{subStringMax3}");
            }
            else                // is empty
            {
                sb.Append($"{subStringMax3}");
            }
        }

        string outputString = sb.ToString();    // <- here is your output
```